# Extract salesforce data in snowflake

Tags: stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In snowflake I have to establish a connection to salesforce with salesforce api url. I dont have ETL tool. Based on the connection setup I should read the data from salesforce object with in snowflake procedure using Javascript Language. By running the stored procedure it should fetch the data and load into snowflake table.How I can read the data from salesforce to snowflake as I dont see any connector in snowflake for salesforce.

Comment: Hi, it can be done using CRM Analytics Snowflake connector  , pl check the link  https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.bi_integrate_connectors_output_snowflake.htm&type=5

Comment: Hi - you haven’t actually asked a question. What have you tried and what issues are you facing? When you researched this, what questions came up that you want help answering?